# Перетаскивание (jQuery dragg) не работает

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, есть вот такой див и код, но почему-то drag дива не происходит. В чем может быть ошибка, подскажете?

```
<div id="block" style="z-index: 33; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -222px; margin-top: -150px; display: block; ">некоторый текст</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#block").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: проверьте пути к скриптам

Comment: пути правильные подключены,скрипты и версии которые используються jquery 1.8 и jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А откуда вы взяли версию **jQuery UI 1.8.9**? Сейчас используется [1.8.22](http://jqueryui.com/download) Подключите:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

И be happy! ))